# Auto change order status from hold-on to processing in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I would like to **change** **every** **order** **from** woocommerce with the status **'HOLD-ON'** **to 'PROCESSING'** *with php*.

I already tried to write a function *in the functions.php* file but I failed.

How can I auto change order status from "hold-on" to "processing" in Woocommerce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To auto-process orders, you should try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_auto_processing_orders');
function woocommerce_auto_processing_orders( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // If order is "on-hold" update status to "processing"
    if( $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'processing' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'ts_auto_complete_by_payment_method');

function ts_auto_complete_by_payment_method($order_id)
{

if ( ! $order_id ) {
return;
}

global $product;
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

if ($order->data['status'] == 'on-hold') {
$payment_method=$order->get_payment_method();
if ($payment_method!="COD")  // change payment method 
{
$order->update_status( 'processing' );
}}}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Add code to your child theme’s functions.php file or via a plugin that allows custom functions to be added, such as the Code snippets plugin. Avoid adding custom code directly to your parent theme’s functions.php file as this will be wiped entirely when you update the theme.

You could also change the “Completed” status to be another order status, like “Processing”

````
   **
* Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
   if ( ! $order_id ) {
       return;
   }

   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   $order->update_status( 'processing' );
} ```
````